# How to have shared functionality between a service and directive

Tags: angularjs

I have some common functionality between a directive and a service.  I'd really like to not copy the code between the two items.  Is it possible to inject a service into a directive?

Comment: Good post about what can be injected: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16828287/what-things-can-be-injected-into-others-in-angular-js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.  In your directive simply do this:

```
.directive('directiveName', ['ServiceName', function(ServiceName) {
  return {
    link: function(...) {
      ServiceName.doSomething();
    }
  }
}]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, that's like one the main things services are for. You can inject to the outer function of your directive declaration:

```
myModule.directive('myDirective', function(awesomeService) {
  return {
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      awesomeService.doSomethingAwesome();
    }
  };
});
```

Or, if your directive is using a controller, just inject it there:

```
var myDirectiveCtrl = function(awesomeService) {
  awesomeService.doSomethingAwesome();
};

myModule.directive('myDirective', function() {
  return {
    controller: myDirectiveCtrl,
    require: 'myDirectiveCtrl',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs, ctrl) {
      ctrl.doStuffMaybe();
    }
  };
});
```