# Angular 1: $injector can't find a provider dependency when injecting provider inside a provider

Tags: angularjs, dependency-injection

My use case is: we have several helper classes, A and B, that are services, A depends on B, and I wanted to make them providers so that they can be used in .config phase.

I followed [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30744757/245966) to load a provider inside a provider.

As you can see here, it works:

http://plnkr.co/edit/SIvujHt7bprFumhxwJqD?p=preview

```
var coreModule = angular.module('CoreModule', []);
coreModule.provider('Car', function() {
  //CarProvider.engine
  this.engine = 'big engine';

  //Car
  this.$get = function() {
    return {
      color: 'red'
    };
  };
});
coreModule.provider('ParameterService', ['$injector', function($injector) {
  try {
    var CarProvider = $injector.get('CarProvider');
    this.deepEngine = CarProvider.engine;
    console.log('deepEngine = ' + this.deepEngine);
  } catch (e) {
    console.log("nope!")
  }

  // ParameterService
  this.$get = function() {
    return {};
  };
}]);
coreModule.config(function(CarProvider) {
  console.log('configEngine = ' + CarProvider.engine); // big engine
});
```

This works if I have `Car` and `ParameterService` in one file in this order.

However when I split `Car` and `ParameterService` into multiple files on disk, or I define `ParameterService` before `Car` in the same file,  `$injector.get('CarProvider')` inside `ParameterService` fails.

How do I fix the issue?

I want to have one provider/service per file and I don't understand what is missing.

Comment: Can you provide a plunker where it fails (separated files)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The order in which the services are defined doesn't matter during run phase, where service instances are injected. But it does matter during configuration phase, where service providers are injected, i.e. in `provider` constructors and `config` blocks.

Providers and config blocks are executed in the order in which they are defined. If `Car` provider is defined after `ParameterService` provider or `config` block, `CarProvider` doesn't exist at the moment when those two are executed.

To avoid potential race conditions, one module per file pattern should be followed. This allows to keep the app highly modular (also beneficial for testing) and never care about the order in which the files are loaded. E.g.:

```
angular.module('app', ['app.carService', 'app.parameterService']).config(...);

angular.module('app.carService', []).provider('Car', ...);

angular.module('app.parameterService', []).provider('ParameterService', ...);
```

Module parts are executed in the order in which the modules are defined in `angular.module` array hierarchy, from children to parents.

The decision if `config` block needs its own module depends on what it does (mostly for testing reasons).

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to have providers in different files. You just need to attach them to the first module that you created.

If your markup looks like this:

```
<script src="coreModule.js"></script>
<script src="parameterService.js"></script>
```

Then, in coreModule.js, define your module:

```
angular.module('CoreModule', [])
    .provider('Car', function() {
        ...
    }
```

Remember, the second parameter (`[]`) tells angular to create a new module.

Then, declare your other provider in a different file, and attach it to your existing 'CoreModule' module:

```
angular.module('CoreModule')
.provider('ParameterService', ['$injector', function($injector) {
    ...
}
```

Notice that we are only passing one parameter to `.module()`. This tells angular to add your provider to an existing module.

[Plunkr Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/rEo9xiKDQyi6aXOpHOWE?p=preview)

Comment: I see what you mean but I don't believe this is the issue. I will try to make a better plunk later (no computer access now)

Comment: Did you take a look at the Plunkr demo?